# Where did poor London women give birth in the latter half of the 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, england, women, london, childbirth

I have a personal reason for asking this question. I'm researching my family tree and I have some ancestors who lived in Mile End **Old** Town, London between 1850 and 1900, but gave birth in [Mile End **New** Town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile_End_New_Town), London which was a nearby but not neighbouring area.

[image: Civil parishes of Whitechapel, 1870]

Mile End **New** Town is in the pinky/purply area at the left, and Mile End **Old** Town is in grey close to the centre of the map.

I've looked on a modern map of London and I can't see a hospital in the area that used to be Mile End **New** Town, although the Royal London Hospital (then just the London Hospital) was nearby, possibly in Mile End **Old** Town.

However, according to [this page](http://www.elenagreene.com/childbirth.html), the poor did not give birth in hospitals in Victorian times anyway.

It seems women, or at least my ancestors, didn't give birth at home but went to a specific place to have their babies. Where did they go?

Comment: Maybe at their mother's or sister's house?

Comment: Intuitively, if the midwife doesn't come to your place, it seems logical that you'd go to the midwife's place -- whoever that was. That said, [are you sure](http://www.elenagreene.com/childbirth.html#victorian) about your assertion that the poor didn't go to some kind of hospital? Anecdotally, and if memory serves me well, the fact that doctors should wash there hands before helping women with childbirth was discovered at a poors' hospital.

Comment: I can't write an answer right now, but look up the Vallance Road Workhouse, which IIRC was in Mile End New Town, and built in the 1840s.

Comment: If you have the birth certificate(s) for your ancestors, the place(s) of birth should appear in the first column "_When and Where Born_".

Comment: @sempaiscuba I have the information extracted from the birth certificates, but not the certificates (or images) themselves. The multiple England and Wales censuses I've found show the whole family lived in Mile End Old Town and birth certificates for all the children say Mile End New Town. No more information than that is available to me.

Comment: @CJDennis That's one reason why it is often worth getting the full certificate when researching your family history.  There can be a lot of useful information beyond the basic date, name & parents.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Possibly. I've seen images of other documentation that contain no extra untranscribed information, and I've found a LOT of relatives, so it could quickly become very expensive for no benefit.

Comment: @CJDennis Yes, it is very expensive in England and Wales, but I've known several people who have solved 'brick walls' with the small details to be found on BMD certificates.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy the hand washing was [Ignaz Semmelweis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignaz_Semmelweis) at Vienna General Hospital

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the sentiment in my earlier comment, [hospitals were chiefly a venue where the poor would go](http://adelaidia.sa.gov.au/subjects/19th-century-childbirth) until the mid-century, and births occurred at home with ad hoc midwives otherwise.

The [story behind hand washing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignaz_Semmelweis) before childbirth (an interesting read in its own right) elaborates on the reasons why hospitals attracted the poor:

> Maternity institutions were set up all over Europe to address problems of infanticide of illegitimate children. They were set up as gratis institutions and offered to care for the infants, which made them attractive to underprivileged women, including prostitutes. In return for the free services, the women would be subjects for the training of doctors and midwives.

The article further notes that Semmelweis' theories were rather well received in the UK. So I'd suggest that a poor in London in the send half of the 19th century would indeed have given birth at the hospital (or more specifically a maternity institution) if they couldn't afford a midwife, and at home if they could.

Comment: The only "hospital" in the district of Mile End New Town in the 2nd half of the 19th C was the [Whitechapel Union Workhouse](https://www.british-history.ac.uk/survey-london/vol27/pp265-288) in Vallance Road, which became the Whitechapel Union Infirmary in 1876, & St Peter's Hospital in 1924.  Workhouses fulfilled the function of hospitals for the poor in England for most of the 19th C.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Interesting. It's rather late over here so I won't read the link until tomorrow, but... Is that to say the answer is wrong in your opinion, or merely incomplete?

Comment: @sempaiscuba According to that link "The [Mile End New Town] workhouse still existed in 1829 (fn. 45) but it was closed after the passing of the Poor Law Amendment Act of 1834. The buildings were demolished by 1838, when the site and four more houses adjoining on the east side were conveyed to the Church Building Commissioners." So it looks like it wasn't in service in the latter half of the 19th century.

Comment: @CJDennis Read further down.  _Mile End New Town Workhouse_ was not the same place as the _Whitechapel Union Workhouse_.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Sorry, I only saw one mention of "Workhouse" in the index. It's possible that's where women gave birth as it seemed to be mostly concerned with children's health.

Comment: @CJDennis To the best of my knowledge, the Workhouse carried a considerable stigma. Most women gave birth at home in London in the 19th century, but if circumstances required it, the nearest thing to a hospital for most poor people was the Workhouse.  The Salvation Army [Mothers' Hospital](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/0a3d7c59-2078-49fc-a9f6-58d051a0e4dd) opened in 1886 to help unmarried mothers, but otherwise, women generally gave birth at home.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Unless you can give a explanation for the consistency of multiple birth certificates and censuses saying they were all born in one place and all lived in another place, I'll take the documents at face value.

Comment: @CJDennis But you don't have all the documents, so you don't have that information.  You need the _actual address_ from the birth certificate if you want to be able to say exactly where they were born.  I understand that pdf copies of certificates currently cost £7.00 each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98442/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-sempaiscuba).